# IOS:Remove view when clicked in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-event

I am doing app related to custom alert. Written code for displaying alert view with transparent background when i click ok button on alert-view an alert disappears.

I need help for same thing happen while i touch the transparent view also my code is a below
:

```
- (void)didCustomPopUpAlertLoad:(UIView *)parentView andtitle:(NSString *)strTitle {

[self setRootView:parentView];
self.lblAlertMessage.text = strTitle;

//Add alertview into transparent view to hide parent view interaction
UIView *transparentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:parentView.bounds];
[transparentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[transparentView addSubview:self];

float x = (int)(transparentView.bounds.size.width - self.bounds.size.width)>>1;
float y = (int)(transparentView.bounds.size.height - self.bounds.size.height)>>2;
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y+62, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];

//    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(x+10, y+62, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
[self.window addSubview:transparentView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[[transparentView subviews]
 makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:)
 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE]];


}
 -(void)didCustomPopUpUnload{

[self.superview removeFromSuperview];
// Set up the fade-in animation
self.window = nil;

 }

 -(IBAction)didActionOkAlertPopUp:(id)sender{

[self didCustomPopUpUnload];
 }
```

Comment: add a tap gesture on tansparent view.

Comment: If your transparent view's size is not equal to the window's size, when you touch the area outside the transparent view, you will never detect the touch. If you cann't full screen the transparent view, you should learn the hitTest, otherwise just add a gesture or override the touches event.

Comment: If you can't fullscreen, you should add another transparent view to the current window to test the touches, and override method 'hitTest:withEvent:'

Comment: i had transparentview i.e it has size of parent view when i click on the transparent view it should disappear .please provide a snippet of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom transparent view then override this method

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Add your alert view into this view and use this view as full screen view.
You can use `event` param to calculate to know user touch inside or outside of alertview.